# How to get aws credentials in react app hosted inside aws elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to use api gateway in my client side app which was developed in react.js.I have hosted the standalone react.js app inside elastic beanstalk.I have used aws-sdk with STS service to get accesskey,secretKey etc.. from STS by using sts.assumeRole. But every time it is giving me

Uncaught (in promise) CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config

For STS service params I am using elasticbeanstalk service role

```
 const params = {
      RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::********:role/aws-elasticbeanstalk- 
 service-role',
 RoleSessionName: 'AccountCredentials',
 DurationSeconds: 3600,
 };
 const assumeRoleData = await sts.assumeRole(params).promise();
```

I am using create-react-app for react.js and I don't want to write any server side node.js code.Any way aws-sdk will work with Javascript so it should work alone with react.js .Please help

Comment: Your React client should have permission for creating STS Client.

Comment: is there any specific policy need to be attached?Can you please provide the details?

Comment: No need policy. You have to add Access and secret key in client side

Comment: Thanks.But I don't want to add Access and secret in client side.Instead of that I want to get those keys by using STS.That's what my whole purpose of this problem statement

Comment: You did not realize use cases of STS

Comment: ok.As of my knowledge STS will be used to give access to 3rd party or cross account access.But any way I will read STS docs one more time.But tell me one thing I want to access AWS service on client side with out keeping my access key and secret key directly in code or in env variables.is it possible?or we have to access via server side code only?

Comment: You that way you can use only serverside. You have to attach STS role to AWS EC2 instance then you can create new client without secret and access key

Comment: ok.I am looking for that answer.So in that case I have to use role based STS only on server side code.In client side we can not use even though client is also running inside EC2.Please correct if I am missing some info.